# Why is this the "most general" first order ODE that can be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Braun's book (p. 58)](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Differential_Equations_and_Their_Applica/CCABCAAAQBAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=1&dq=%22clearly+the+most+general+first-order+differential+equation+that+we+can+solve%22&pg=PA58&printsec=frontcover) says that the ODE
$$\frac{d}{dt}[\Phi(t,y)]=0\tag{1}$$
is

> *clearly the most general first-order differential equation
> that we can solve*.

Of course, all equations having that form can be  (implicitly) solved:
$$\Phi(t,y)=c.$$

However, the converse (stated by Braun) is not "clear" for me. So, how could we explain it? For example, the most general first-order ODE is
$$F(t,y,y')=0.\tag{2}$$
Suppose that this ODE have a solution
$$G(t,y)=0.\tag{3}$$

Doesn't Braun's statement mean that (2) and (3) imply that $(2)$ can be written in the form (1)? If so, how to prove it? If not, what does Braun mean?

Comment: I wouldn't pay too much attention to this kind of comments. Sometimes these do more harm than good. Just move on to the theorems. In 2011, I got the following advice from Willie Wong [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51044/8157): "In any case, whenever you see sweeping statements like this made in books or articles, you should always take them with a grain of salt and treat them more like guiding principles rather than precise definitions." Fourteen years after I can confirm that this advice is really solid.

Comment: Perhaps this is just his definition of what it means for the equation to be "solvable". If the equation cannot be put in that form, then maybe a solution exists but we can't find it by anti-differentiating.

Comment: @mr_e_man: I think you are right. That should be an answer. (In my previous comment, "fourteen" should be replaced by "twelve", of course! :-) )

Comment: Parametric solutions of the form $f(x, \tau, C)=0$, $g(y, \tau, C)=0$ might be considered a more general form of solveable ODEs. Consider, for instance, the ODE \begin{align}
yy'=y+Ax,
\end{align}
with general solution
\begin{align}
x=C\exp\left(\int\frac{-\tau\mathrm d\tau}{\tau^2-\tau-A}\right),\quad y=C\tau \exp\left(\int\frac{-\tau\mathrm d\tau}{\tau^2-\tau-A}\right)
\end{align}
Finding $\tau(x)$ (and $\Phi(x,y,C)=0$) is not feasible in this case and most all other cases where solutions of $yy'=y+f(x)$ are known.